# How to apply aggregate function on time?

Tags: sql, unicode

Suppose I have multiple time values in column `time_max` and I want avg. of all.

I am not able to perform the same.

PFB query I am using

```
select avg(d_run_start_time)
  from gaurav_job_log
 where fic_mis_date>='15/Nov/2013'
   and fic_mis_date <='15/Feb/2014'
   and v_interface_id like '%BUDA_PEST_first_cut%' 
 group by v_interface_id ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I'm puzzled why you have the 'unicode' tag on this question which seems to be an SQL question. I've added the 'sql' tag; it would be a good idea to add a tag for your particular DBMS too, and I think the 'unicode' tag should go. As to technical content, it may be that your DBMS follows the strict ISO SQL rules and you can't add a bunch of time values; you can only take the difference (creating an INTERVAL). Maybe you can use `SELECT AVG(d_run_start_time - TIME(00:00:00))` which subtracts midnight from the time and gives an INTERVAL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST(AVG(CAST(d_run_start_time AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) as Avgdatetime
  from gaurav_job_log
 where fic_mis_date>='15/Nov/2013'
   and fic_mis_date <='15/Feb/2014'
   and v_interface_id like '%BUDA_PEST_first_cut%' 
 group by v_interface_id ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent SQL as code by selecting the code in the edit box and then pressing the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  It will greatly improve the readability of the code.